# Algolia search only by distance

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to rank search results based solely on proximity (and other filters) to a specific point and ignore the custom ranking formula (`likes`)?

For example, I'd like to rank results closest to times square strictly by distance and for the query to not care about the `likes` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `likes` attributes is one of you own.
You can do what you need by removing the attribute `like` from the custom ranking.
If you need 2 way to search, you can do a replica index, with the same data but a different ranking formula: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/sorting/?language=go#multiple-sorting-strategies-for-an-index